# cambiar extensión de url en una ruta con id

Tags: php, laravel, url

Trato de ocultar la extensión de una Url de modo que pase de

```
pagina/link/9
```

a

```
pagina/link
```

Cuando se visualiza en el navegador.
Mi link funciona asi:

```
<a href="{{ route('BLC.get',Crypt::encrypt($FlujoTabla->idFlujos))}}" target="_blank">
```

mi ruta

```
Route::get('/PRIMBLC/{idFlujos}', 'HomeController@PRIMBLC')->name('PRIMBLC.get');
```

mi controlador

```
    public function PRIMBLC($id)
    {
...
...
$id =  Crypt::decrypt($id); // desencripto mi ID 
$Respuestas = Respuestas::all();
$Flujos = Flujos::findOrFail($id);

    return view('PRIMBLC', compact('Respuestas','Flujo'));
    }
```

Cuando se ve mi url con la encriptado se ve algo asi:

```
 pagina/link/#$%&//
```

pero si altero un poco la url de la pagina de error de sistema de laravel con el mensaje :

```
Illuminate \ Contracts \ Encryption \ DecryptException
The payload is invalid.
```

me gustaría poder redirecionar a mi vista de error de laravel o poder ocultar el parametro que manda a la nueva pagina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que tu sistema de encriptar esta encriptando con caracteres especiales . Lo que estas recibiendo en la variable **$id** no es **#$%&//**. Has un dump y lo veras.

en tu Blade escribe algo asi :

```
base64_encode(Crypt::encrypt($FlujoTabla->idFlujos))
```

En tu función PRIMBLC escribe algo así:

```
$id =  Crypt::decrypt(base64_decode($id));
```

Esto hará que cualquier carácter reservado para QueryStrings no tenga conflicto al hacer la petición.

Comment: gracias ! la verdad no me funciono al 100% pero me dio una idea que quise probar igual que en tu ejemplo mande el link encriptado y desencripte como decías, pero llegue al mismo resultado en ese caso opte por colocar una función dentro de la ruta que lansara el elemento re encriptado en Crypt y base 64 y sumado a tu solución se soluciono (si se ve algo enredado pero se ve bien! gracias! )

Comment: no entendí muy bien lo que hicies pero me alegra que se solucionara!. el problema en si son los caracteres especiales que devuelve Crypt::encrypt envolviéndolos con base64 te olvidas de problemas con caracteres especiales en el query string! Saludos!.

Comment: si, exactamente los caracteres especiales fueron lo que se complico pero al tener esa idea en mente el resto se soluciono faci :) , gracias